# How to apply neural networks on multi-label classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, multilabel

**Description:**

Let the problem domain be document classification where there exists a set of feature vectors, each belonging to 1 or more classes. For example, a document `doc_1` might belong to `Sports` and `English` categories.

**Question:**

Using neural network for classification, what would the label be for a feature vector? would it be a vector constituting of all the classes such that 0 value is given to non-relevant classes and 1 for relevant classes? So if the class labels' list is `[Sports, News, Action, English, Japanese]`, then for document `doc_1` the label would be `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in multi-label learning the label information is often encoded as the binary vector you described. It is also easier so for evaluation.

We may want to check [MULAN](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/), an open source Java library for multi-label learning. It is a Weka extension and has implemented many multi-label classifiers, neural networks included. For example, you can find BP-MLL [here](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/doc/mulan/classifier/neural/BPMLL.html).

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be the paper you are looking for:

[Min-Ling Zhang and Zhi-Hua Zhou: Multi-Label Neural Networks with Applications to
Functional Genomics and Text Categorization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.130.7318&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

From the abstract:

> In multi-label learning, each instance in the training set is
>   associated with a set of labels, and the task is to output a label set
>   whose size is unknown a priori for each unseen instance.In this paper,
>   this problem is addressed in the way that a neural network algorithm
>   named BP-MLL, i.e. Backpropagation for Multi-Label Learning, is
>   proposed. ... Applications to two real- world multi-label learning problems, i.e.
>   functional genomics and text categorization, show that the performance
>   of BP-MLL is superior to those of some well-established multi-label
>   learning algorithms.